# UIBarBUttonItem image

Tags: image, uibarbuttonitem

I have a toolbar created programaticaly with 3 buttons (only 1 shown here). After a lot of Googling I was able to set a nice background image but now I don't know where to put
the code for the `action: target:self action:@selector(pressButton3:)` method. So I have a non-working button with nice colorful image. I've tried a lot of examples and if the button is working the image is not working and vice versa. Please help.

```
//Add buttons
UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"mapp.png"];

UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button setImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, buttonImage.size.width, buttonImage.size.height);

UIBarButtonItem *systemItem1 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];
[systemItem1 initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(pressButton1:)];

//add to array
 NSArray *items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: systemItem1, nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're button should work if you add:

```
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(pressButton1:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

And remove the line:

```
[systemItem1 initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(pressButton1:)];
```